# rendering of the child component

Tags: reactjs, usecallback, react-usememo

I have a child component:

```
const MemoModalWindow = memo(ModalWindow)
<MemoModalWindow show={show} handleClose={handleClose} rowValue={first} />
```

I pass props to it

```
show={show} - boolean,
handleClose={handleClose} - function, 
rowValue={**first**} - object,
```

And when I try to change the **first** object in the parent component, I have a re-render

```
const [first, setfirst] = useState<any>()
const handleClick = () => {
    setfirst({ id: 123 })
}

<button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
```

After clicking on the button, my components will be re-rendered

How can I avoid rendering my child component?

Comment: If you don't want it to re-render, why did you send it to the child component as a prop?

Comment: A `state` is meant to rerender your components. If you don't want to rerender, use a `variable` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-rendering occurs only when the state updates. So you can use a variable instead of a state for 'first.'

```js
let first;
const handleCick = () => {
    first = {id: 123}
}
```